# How to shutdown Wildfly 10.0 properly?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ear, wildfly-10

I am running Wildfly 10.0 inside Amazon AWS EC2 instance.
Everything is running fine.
But when I am trying to shutdown the wildfly the server, it's undeploying the deployed EAR file.
I am using the below command to start and stop the server.

START:

```
nohup /data/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/bin/standalone.sh -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/security/jssecacerts" --server-config=standalone.xml &
```

STOP:

```
sh /data/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:shutdown
```

After executing the shutdown command, I am getting this in server.log

```
2017-04-04 08:38:35,062 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) WFLYDR0009: Content /data/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/data/content/dd/66eee901c4bf79dd6659873df918e1b639bc1b is obsolete and will be removed
2017-04-04 08:38:35,073 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location /data/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/data/content/dd/66eee901c4bf79dd6659873df918e1b639bc1b/content
```

We are not facing this issue in local windows environment or any other Linux environment.
It's happening only in Amazon AWS EC2 environment where the operating system is Redhat.

Comment: Is it not working correctly when you restart? All deployments are undeployed when the server is shutdown.

Comment: I haven't tried with restart. I will give it a try. But we are not facing this issue in local windows environment or other Linux environment. Even after shutdown we are not loosing out deployed applications and can access them after starting the server again.

Comment: I tried with restart option as well.
But still I am getting the same issue. I observed that if I shutdown and start the server without any time gap, then it's working fine. But if I wait for 5 mins or more after the shutdown operation, then I am facing this problem while starting the server. Unable to start the server because some obsolete traces of deployment gets created in standalone.xml.

Comment: Any thought on this James ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what it could be. The content doesn't look like it should be deleted, but I'm not very familiar with the deployment repository code so I'm not sure how it determines what is obsolete and what is not. You could file an issue here though http://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE

Comment: How long does it take for the server to shutdown? How was the server installed (rpm or untaring) ? Could you give us more info on your application ?

Comment: It takes less than 10 secs to shutdown the server. Once I get success message for shutdown, after few minutes server.log gets updated with message which says the content is obsolete and it will be deleted.

We have installed wildfly by downloading the tar.gz file and then running tar -xvf command. It's a redhat system running inside AWS EC2 instance.

It's not related specifically to my application or its .ear file. Even if I deploy a sample web application with just an index.jsp file, I am getting the same issue.

Comment: Could you put the server logging in trace mode ? Is the user executing wildfly the same as the user that has installed it ? According to what you are writing you are getting a SUCCESS on the CLI for the server to shutdown but the process is still running, could you confirm that ?

Comment: I didn't get anything useful in trace mode log.
I installed the wildfly server by using these commands.
sudo wget http://download.jboss.org/wildfly/10.1.0.Final/wildfly-10.1.0.Final.tar.gz

sudo tar -xzf wildfly-10.1.0.Final.tar.gz

And running the shutdown and startup commands by executing it with sudo. Hence installation and execution both are being done by root user.

I am getting a SUCCESS on CLI after executing shutdown command and the process is successfully terminating as well. But after server stops, the ear is getting un-deployed.

Comment: Could you try https://www.dropbox.com/s/ueaurw8jseyvoum/wildfly-10.1.0.Final.tar.gz?dl=0 ? I may have found a fix.